# If RS is equivalent to SR, then R*S* is equivalent to S*R* (Proof by Contradiction)

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, regular-expressions

R and S are arbitrary regular expressions. I need a counter example where this is not true. I am unable to figure this out.

Comment: Better ask at the computer science stack exchange to get an answer.

Comment: in fact, why do you think it is not true? At a second thought, given that for any $r\in R, s\in S$ there exists $r'\in R, s'\in S$ s.t. $rs = s'r'$ (comm), one could prove that $R^*S^*$ and $S^*R^*$. Say one wants to show that $S^iR^j$ is in $R^*S^*$; take an arbitrary word from $S^iR^j$; it's of the form $s_1...s_ir_1...r_j$. One only needs to apply $i$ times the property (comm) to bring each $r_k$ to the front and finally after $i*j$ moves one gets $r'_1..r'_js'_1...s'_i$ which is a word in $R^*S^*$.

Comment: @r-zu This site created the tags *computer science*, *regular-language*, *regular-expressions* precisely for this kind of question, which is perfectly welcome on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $RS = SR$. I claim that $R^*S^* = S^*R^*$.

**Step 1**. Let us first show by induction on $m$ that for every $m \geqslant 0$, 
$$
(1) \quad RS^m = S^mR.
$$ 
If $m = 0$, then $S^m = 1$, the language reduced to the empty word, and the result is trivial. If $m > 0$, then $RS^m = RSS^{m-1} = SRS^{m-1}$ and by the induction hypothesis $RS^{m-1} = S^{m-1}R$. Thus $RS^m = S^mR$.

**Step 2**. Let us prove by induction on $n$ that for all $n,m \geqslant 0$,
$$
(2) \quad R^nS^m = S^mR^n.
$$ 
Again, the case $n = 0$ is trivial. If $n > 0$, then $R^nS^m = RR^{n-1}S^m$ and by the induction hypothesis, $R^{n-1}S^m = S^mR^{n-1}$. It follows that $R^nS^m = RS^mR^{n-1}$. using (1), one gets $RS^m = S^mR$ and thus $R^nS^m = S^mRR^{n-1} = S^mR^n$ as required.

**Final step**. One has 
$$
R^*S^* = \Bigl(\sum_{n \geqslant 0} R^n\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{m \geqslant 0} S^m\Bigr) = \sum_{n, m \geqslant 0} R^nS^m = \sum_{n, m \geqslant 0} S^mR^n = \Bigl(\sum_{m \geqslant 0} S^m\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{n \geqslant 0} R^n\Bigr) = S^*R^*
$$